# How does Aluminum react with nitric acid at different concentrations?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am unable to find proper information. My book just says that conc. Nitric acid renders it passive.Could anyone please give the different reactions at different concentrations

Comment: No...I want the different reactions at different concentrations

Comment: Al don't react with HNO3 at any concentration. Asking same question about Fe would make more sense

Comment: It does react. I have read it somewhere

Comment: You want an exact answer where there is none. The passivation can be broken, but then there will be a wide variety of products. There is nothing exact about it.

Comment: Anymore problems in the language of question for anyone please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer per this source: ['Reaction of aluminium with diluted nitric acid containing dissolved sodium chloride'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215904038_Reaction_of_aluminium_with_diluted_nitric_acid_containing_dissolved_sodium_chloride_On_the_nature_of_the_gaseous_products), is apparently **no** with respect to both dilute and concentrated nitric acid, except... to quote:

> Metallic aluminium was found not to react with either concentrated or diluted nitric acid. Providing the diluted acid contains dissolved sodium chloride and traces of copper(II) cations, a vigorous reaction occurs. The product is basically nitrous oxide (possibly containing some elemental hydrogen and nitrogen gases), and was identified by its IR spectrum.

The qualifications for dissolution is interesting as it amounts basically to a galvanic cell anodic dissolution (think 'Bleach Battery' variation with HNO3 in place of HOCl and a copper metal electrode, the latter created from Aluminum displacing Cu(II) ions forming a Cu cathode on the Al surface).

[EDIT] Note: The above electrochemical viewpoint may apparently be a unique perspective on my part relating to the underlying reaction mechanics in conjunction with the role of NaCl in penetrating the protective Al2O3 layer (however, the author does also employ the phrase 'dissociation of the electrolytes'). Otherwise, the author does not explicitly mention 'electrochemical' anywhere in the article except in reference to the 'electrochemical series of elements'.

Answer (score 0):

According to ASM ,(8 th ed. , vol 2), 5 to 20 % nitric can be used to clean aluminum for spot welding It is not intended to passivate or anodize. It was one of very many cleaning options.